# Handling different input date formats to insert into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How to best to handle different date formats on an input field that is entered in by a user to format it correctly to insert into MySQL date field (Y-m-d). One potential solution is to tell the user to always enter in the correct format in the 3rd party application. However, I wanted to create safeguards in case the input field comes across incorrectly.

Some potential date formats (could be more)

```
$variable = '11-13-18'
//$variable = '2018/11/13'
//$variable = '18/11/13'
//$variable = '2018/11/13'

$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $variable)));
```

When I tested '11-13-18' and '11-13-2018' both failed and within the database, it inserted a generic '1969-12-31'.

Comment: The user should provide the date in a specific format. If you need to let the user provide date values in a variety of formats, then the user also needs to provide another field that identifies what format the date is in.  Otherwise, how do we know what format the date is supplied in? Consider how we would interpret a value of '08-06-04'. Would we see that as June 4, 2008? August 6, 2004? April 6?

Comment: @spencer7593 gotcha, thanks for advice.

Comment: @user3783243 the data is coming across from a 3rd party interface which doesn't allow datepicker

Comment: Ah, missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-','/', $variable)));
```

Output:

```
2018-11-13
```